# Chrome Extension Event Page communicating with external native host

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I'm building a Chrome Extension that, through a native host, should simulate a key press. I can connect to my native host to check that it's there etc in the popup I've created, but in my event page script, should I just connect to the native host? It says on the Chrome Extension Developer Page that:

*Event pages are loaded only when they are needed. When the event page is not actively doing something, it is unloaded, freeing memory and other system resources.*

So if I want it to run "forever", i.e. listen to the native host and simulating a key press whenever it gets a "ping", how should I do that? The page says I should create events for that, but do I just listen to the port then?

Thanks,

Johan

Comment: You can consider using a [`background page`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) for your "forever" requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as there is an open port opened with `connect()`, an Event page will not shut down.

If you think it's going to be like that most of the time, don't bother with Event pages and put `"persistent": true` (or nothing) to make a normal background one.